# Fullscreen background staying center when resizing

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm creating a website with a fullscreen video background. I want it to stay at 100% height all the time, and cut out everything that doesn't fit in the aspect ratio given by the browser. I've succeded in doing so, but now I want the movie to stay center at all times.

How to?

My code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Background Video</title>

<style>
body{ margin:0px; background:#000; }
#bg_container{ height:100%; width:auto; }
#bg{ height:100%;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="bg_container">
<video id="bg" src="video/video.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted="true"></video>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: than wait i am doing your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code is here>>>>> [**Fullscreen center video background**](http://jsfiddle.net/5xkVp/)

---

add this link into head

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

**HTML**

---

```
<video id = "video_background" preload = "auto" autoplay = "true" loop = "loop">
  <source src = "http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type = "video/mp4" />
</video>
```

**css**

---

```
  #video_background{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 4000%;
    max-height:4000%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**javascript**

---

```
    // Resize the video elements so that we don't get any borders due to aspect ratio
function resizeVideo() {
  if ($(window).height() > $(window).width() * 0.5425) { // Which dimension is bigger dependant on aspect ratio (16:9)
    $("video").removeAttr("height").removeAttr("width").width("auto").height("100%");
  }
  else {
    $("video").removeAttr("height").removeAttr("width").width("100%").height("auto");
  }
};


// Add the resize function to the window resize event but put it on a short timer as to not call it too often
var resizeTimer;
$(window).resize(function () {
  clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(resizeVideo, 150);
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. That way it's still just cutting the right side out if I resize the browser window from right to left. I need to be able to see the center part of the video at all times.

Comment: ok so for that you have to change structure of your html and css is that okay?

Comment: Sure - more than okay!

Comment: happy to help! Dont forget to accept my answer and vote up! cheers